# Check if Random number has been allocated to user in time frame

Tags: php, mysql, random

I've got a group of web pages with one image on each. Clicking on the homepage image goes to the next page via an HTML link, which also logs their IP address and the time (using timestamp) they clicked, into an SQL database. Each image is labelled 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc.

I'm trying to make it more random - so instead of 2.jpg being second, it's rand().jpg - given the latter images are rarely viewed. However, being random, it also causes it to repeat; they end up showing certain pages multiple times and others not at all. 
I've tried comparing the random number with other random numbers in the database (as per other Stackoverflow questions), to make sure it's unique, but that means one user views more than other.
It also means that once the users have seen every picture I need to truncate the table or else it won't give any more numbers out.

1) Collect ip address and generate random number.

2) Check database "markers" and select all records with that users ip address from the past hour.

3) Check that array to see if random number is already there.

4)

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$r = (rand(1,12))

// $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
require_once('../includes/ran.php');
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT ip, entrytime, random FROM markers WHERE entrytime>= NOW()- INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND ip LIKE '".$ip."%'");
$result->execute();
// for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){

=====what goes here =======
}
```

Comment: You're preparing, but you're not using *placeholder values*. That's an easy fix that patches a [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Why not generate a random sequence when the page first loads, stick that in a cookie or `$_SESSION`, and then spin through that instead? You could also do this client-side by giving a list of images in advance and let the client jumble them up.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if you want to show a single randomly chosen image to a user on each click, you can do something like

```
      SELECT imagename FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

to get the image to display. But this is a notorious badly-performing way to get a random item.

You could add a column to your images table

```
      DOUBLE random_choice;
```

Then, when you insert data into the table, set random_choice to `RAND()`.

```
 INSERT INTO images (whatever, whatever, random_choice)
             VALUES (??, ??, RAND();
```

Then when selecting a random image you do

```
  SELECT imagename FROM images WHERE random_choice <= RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

This is the way Wikipedia implements "show me a random article." To make this efficient you'll need an index on `random_choice`.

If you must never show the same image to the same user twice until that user has seen all the images, that's a *much* harder problem to solve, especially if your number of users scales up. Can you dodge that requirement?